# how to run specific factory in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, backend, factory, laravel-8

I need to run factory using tinker
but my model isn't in app folder like this->App\Models\User::factory()->count(2)->create();

the path is-> Modules\Menu\Entities\MenuPosition
and when I run tis command

```
php artisan tinker
Modules\Menu\Entities\MenuPosition::factory()->count(2)->create();
```

there is error

```
Class 'Database/Factories/Modules/Menu/Entities/MenuPositionFactory' not found in C:/laragon/www/menu--test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php on line 656
```

Comment: where is your factory class?

Comment: Did you wrote any factory for that model?

Comment: yes I have factory class and the path is->Modules\Menu\Database\Factories\MenuFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `newFactory` method on this model:

```
/**
 * Create a new factory instance for the model.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
 */
protected static function newFactory()
{
    return \Modules\Menu\Database\Factories\MenuFactory::new();
}
```

Or you can look into the documentation to see how to adjust how the factory is looked up based on the model.

Answer (score 4):

you can use like this:

```
\App\Models\User::factory()->count(2)->create();
```

just write the namespace of the model you want to use